# Multiplication factors in folding root systems and Lie algebras by automorphisms

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, root-systems

When Stembridge, in the paper [Folding by automorphisms](https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Ejrs/papers/folding.pdf), considers folding by automorphism $\sigma$ he considers the root system generated by for each orbit $J$.

$$\sum_{i \in J} \alpha_i .$$

Whereas Carter, in Lie Algebras of Finite and Affine Type page 166, he considers generators of the form

$$\frac{1}{|J|}\sum_{i \in J} \alpha_i .$$

I am not sure how to resolve this multiplication factor gives the same results. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I believe they are Langlands dual.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose we fold a root system $(\Phi,\Delta)$ to a root system $(\Phi^\sigma,\Delta^\sigma)$. There exists two conventions:

- long roots of $(\Phi^\sigma,\Delta^\sigma)$ correspond to multiple roots in $(\Phi,\Delta)$; or
- short roots of $(\Phi^\sigma,\Delta^\sigma)$ corresponds to multiple roots in $(\Phi,\Delta)$.

Stembridge uses the first convention:
$$\big(\sum_{i\in J}\alpha_i,\sum_{i\in J}\alpha_i\big)=2|J|,$$
while Carter uses the second convention:
$$\big(\frac1{|J|}\sum_{i\in J}\alpha_i,\frac1{|J|}\sum_{i\in J}\alpha_i\big)=\frac2{|J|}.$$
Note that taking Langlands dual swaps long and short roots, which is why Stembridge's convention and Carter's convention is dual to each other.

P.S. Foldings are explicitly computed in Section 3.5 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2401.06605 (we use Stembridge's conventions)